# What is the best way to know the structure of a database

Tags: sql-server, mysql

One of the things that I spend a lot of time when i start some proyect is to understand the relationships of the database provided, and the results of update or delete some foreign key

what is your way of learn a database structure? maybe you draw on paper? or some software

Answer (score 1):

You can use "database Diagram" and add all tables to get a physical representation of the tables with PK and FK and some link between table but this is certainly not as detailed as you would like it to be.

If you don't have any dev documentation for those DB, that's still bether than nothing and with some manual work to check those link between tables, you can get something that is "workable".

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use this to find all the possible joins in a new DB:

```
with WholeSchema as (
select st.name as tableName, sc.name as columnName from sys.tables st
inner join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id)

select * from WholeSchema s1
inner join WholeSchema s2 on s1.columnName = s2.columnName
where s1.tableName != s2.tableName
```

You will probably want to narrow it down with a where clause.